# Decoding the keys from RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa, .net-5, asn.1

I am trying to extract the private keys from an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object using `.ExportRSAPrivateKey()`. As per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.exportrsaprivatekey?view=net-5.0), it exports a "byte array containing the PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey representation of this key", which representation is defined in [Appendix A of RFC8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1). So based on that, I assume that it should be ASN1-encoded and try to use an `AsnReader` class:

```cs
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
{
    var priv = rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey();
    var asnr = new AsnReader(priv, AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    var N = asnr.ReadInteger();
}
```

However, this code fails on `.ReadInteger()` with exception: `"The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '16', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '2'."`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because RSAPublicKey is a SEQUENCE ...

So you have to read a sequence and then, the integer ...

I guess you are using Microsoft [AsnReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asnreader?view=net-5.0) class

So, the code could be something like:

```
var publicKey = asnr.ReadSequence()
var N = publickKey.ReadInteger()
```